# Cannot bind parameter 'RecoveryPoint'. Cannot convert value "derived class" to type "base class"

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

When running `Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem` to in a script block, the `-RestorePoint` parameter doesn't allow me to pass in a restore point obtained with `Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint`, I get the following error.

```
Cannot bind parameter 'RecoveryPoint'. Cannot convert value "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.AzureVmRecoveryPoint" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.RecoveryPointBase". Error: "Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.AzureVmRecoveryPoint" value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.AzureVmRecoveryPoint" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.RecoveryPointBase"
```

`Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.AzureVmRecoveryPoint` is derived from `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.RecoveryPointBase`, so I'm unsure as to why it's refusing to convert in order to bind to the `-RecoveryPoint` parameter. The code works when not using `Start-Job`, so I guess it's something to do with that.

My code below

```
$recoveryPoints = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint `
    -Item           $backupItem `
    -StartDate      ( (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToUniversalTime() ) `
    -EndDate        ( (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() )

$rp = $recoveryPoints[0]

$scriptBlock = {
    try {
        $restoreJob = Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem `
            -RecoveryPoint     $args[0] `
            -TargetResourceGroupName $args[1] `
            -StorageAccountName $args[2].Name `
            -StorageAccountResourceGroupName $args[2].ResourceGroupName

        Wait-AzRecoveryServicesBackupJob -Job $restoreJob -Timeout 3600
    }
    catch {
        Throw "$_"
    }
}

$asyncJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $rp,$rgName,$storageAccount
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this error is that the `RestorePoint` parameter of the `Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem` expects an object of type `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.RecoveryPointBase`, but you are passing an object of type `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.AzureVmRecoveryPoint`.

So, when you provide the `$rp` object to the `script` block, it gets serialized and deserialized before being passed to the new `PowerShell` process created by `Start-Job`. As this process doesn't have access to the `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.AzureVmRecoveryPoint type`, it cannot properly deserialize the object.

After a workaround on your issue, I found an approach using [`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7.3) command as it creates an `XML` representation of an object and store it in a file.

After that you need to import it using [`Import-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml?view=powershell-7.3) in the current PS Script and it creates the corresponding objects.

```
$rp | Export-Clixml -Path 'xxxx' #serializing the $rp out of the script block
$rp = Import-Clixml -Path 'xxx' #deserializing inside the script block
```

[image]

[image]

Once it is done, use it along with the `Start-Job` command `-argument` parameter.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $rp,$rgName,$storageAccount # Or you can directly pass the deserialized path in place of `$rp` variable
```